# If this spook is a U-boat, he might pull the plug

Tags: meaning

Here's from the movie The Enemy Below(1957).
You can watch it on youtube.

10:35

> It might be a fishing smack or... well, it
>   might be the conning tower of a sub, sir.
>   - Bridge. Lieutenant Ware.
>   - Mr Ware.
>   We're about to lose radar contact
>   at the rate we're going.
>   Reduce speed to speed of target
>   and get on its tail.
>   At this distance, we'll
>   make visual contact at daybreak.
>   - Shall I shake the ship out for a standby?
>   - Not much shaking out to be done.
>   But ready underwater search gear.
>   If this spook is a U-boat,
>   he might pull the plug,
>   and we'll have to go after him.

What does "pull the plug" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulling the plug invokes the image of a plug in a bath tub. In a standard bath tub, pulling the plug will cause the water to flow *out* of the tub.

However, if your bath tub is empty, and floating on the sea, pulling the plug will have the opposite effect: water will flow in, and your bath tub will sink.

Apply this image to a boat, and *pulling the plug* would mean *make your boat sink*. Normally that is not something you want to do to your own boat, but a *U-boat* is a submarine.

So a U-boat that *pulls the plug* will ***dive***, i.e. go under water (presumably in order to flee from the protagonist's ship).